# libxgboost4j_gpu.so for x86 architecture inside h2o.jar for ppc64le

Tags: h2o, driverless-ai, ppc64le

I am trying out DAI 1.4.2 on ppc64le Redhat with V100 GPUs, but I find some weird error with dai-h2o daemon.

It seems like it cannot initialize its GPU backend, and I find libxgboost4j_gpu.so for x86 architecture (not ppc64le) inside h2o.jar.

Is this some kind of bug or doesn't this matter at all ?

```
[root@localhost home]# systemctl status dai-h2o
● dai-h2o.service - Driverless AI (H2O Process)
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dai-h2o.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/dai-h2o.service.d
       └─Group.conf, User.conf
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2018-12-17 14:51:23 KST; 1s ago
 Main PID: 80685 (java)
    Tasks: 93
   Memory: 155.8M
   CGroup: /system.slice/dai-h2o.service
           └─80685 
/opt/h2oai/dai/jre/bin/java -Xmx65536m -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -Ddai.tmp=./tmp -jar /opt/h2oai/dai/h...

Dec 17 14:51:24 localhost.localdomain dai-env.sh[80685]: ======================================================================
 Dec 17 14:51:25 localhost.localdomain dai-env.sh[80685]: Cannot load library from path lib/linux_64/libxgboost4j_gpu.so
Dec 17 14:51:25 localhost.localdomain dai-env.sh[80685]: Cannot load library from path lib/libxgboost4j_gpu.so
Dec 17 14:51:25 localhost.localdomain dai-env.sh[80685]: Failed to load library from both native path and jar!
Dec 17 14:51:25 localhost.localdomain dai-env.sh[80685]: Cannot load library from path lib/linux_64/libxgboost4j_omp.so
Dec 17 14:51:25 localhost.localdomain dai-env.sh[80685]: Cannot load library from path lib/libxgboost4j_omp.so
Dec 17 14:51:25 localhost.localdomain dai-env.sh[80685]: Failed to load library from both native path and jar!
Dec 17 14:51:25 localhost.localdomain dai-env.sh[80685]: Cannot load library from path lib/linux_64/libxgboost4j_minimal.so
Dec 17 14:51:25 localhost.localdomain dai-env.sh[80685]: Cannot load library from path lib/libxgboost4j_minimal.so
Dec 17 14:51:25 localhost.localdomain dai-env.sh[80685]: Failed to load library from both native path and jar!

[root@localhost home]# netstat -an | grep 12345

[root@localhost home]# ls -l 
/opt/h2oai/dai/h2o.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 109623422 Dec  4 07:45 /opt/h2oai/dai/h2o.jar

[root@localhost home]# jar -xvf /opt/h2oai/dai/h2o.jar lib/linux_64/libxgboost4j_gpu.so
 inflated: lib/linux_64/libxgboost4j_gpu.so

[root@localhost home]# ls -l lib/linux_64/libxgboost4j_gpu.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 34754400 Jul  8 12:56 lib/linux_64/libxgboost4j_gpu.so

[root@localhost home]# file lib/linux_64/libxgboost4j_gpu.so
lib/linux_64/libxgboost4j_gpu.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=c7c3682ccf33d3d0395772e924be1e416a60a2c4, not stripped
```

Answer (score 2):

This does not matter at all.

The h2o.jar bundled with Driverless AI is not for GPU use at all.

All of the GPU use is from the Driverless AI python processes.